# Are motorised two-wheelers allowed to drive on bicycle lanes in Belgium?

Tags: legal, driving, belgium, motorcycles, walking

I recently spent a couple days in Belgium. As I was happily walking around the various cities I visited I was nearly ran over thrice by motorised two-wheelers (mopeds, scooters, pizza-delivery guys, you name it) speeding down the bicycle lane. In all instances, I was legally walking on a [shared-use path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_use_path).

Are motorised two-wheelers (mopeds, scooters, motorbikes, trikes) allowed to drive on bicycle lanes in Belgium?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Horizons Unlimited](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/europe/what-european-countries-can-you-81096) 21 Mar 2015 duibhceK:

> In Belgium 25km/h mopeds are obliged to use the cycle path everywhere, unless specific signs forbid it.
>
> 45km/h limited mopeds are obliged to use the cycle path wherever a speed limit higher than 50km/h is in effect. Within zones that have a 50km/h or lower speed limit you can choose whether you use the cycle path or not.
>
> Any moped faster than 45km/h requires a motorcycle license and is not allowed on the cycle path.

But specific signage may overrule general regulations.